# Locking of 2-Dimensional Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have the following class and I want to make the set2Int-method thread-safe. But there should be no lock on the method (with adding synchronize). If the if-condition is true, there should be a lock on both Integers in the array (to avoid deadlocks). It should also be possible to call the method concurrently that means a lock on the whole array is also no desired solution.

```
public class Container {
    private Integer[][] array;

    public Container(int xs, int ys){
       array = new Integer[ys][];
       for (int i = 0; i < xs; i++){
           array[i] = new Integer[xs];
       }   
    }

    public void set2Int(int a, int b){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length - 1; j++){
                if(array[i][j] == 0 && array[i][j+1] == 0){
                    array[i][j] = a;
                    array[i][j+1] = b;
                    return;
                }   
                if(array[i][j] == 0 && array[i+1][j] == 0){
                    array[i][j] = a;
                    array[i+1][j] = b;
                    return;
                } 
            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What have tried? Where is it failing? I don't see any attempt at synchronizing in the code you posted. This is not a site where people will write your code for you - you need to make an effort to make it work, and if something specific is the problem, you can ask about it.

Comment: To lock array elements individually, you'll a separate lock object for each element. It could be done, but is it really worth the extra effort? And what's wrong with just making the method `synchronized` anyway?

Comment: I want to make it possible, that two threads work concurrently on the array, because the array could be very large and just two elements have to be locked.

Comment: Would `synchronize(array[i][j]){
synchronize(array[i][j+1]){
synchronize(array[i+1][j]}}` be an thread-safe solution (inserted before the first if)?

Answer (score 0):

Using locks for every integer might consume some memory. I'd use `int[]` array instead of Integer, and go with lock striping. This means you can keep lesser amount of locks and assign every array cell to one of that locks.

Beside that, I would not lock array cell for reading, use `volatile read` instead. Here is `getOpaque` is used, which provides no synchronization guarantess, but reads value from memory, and JIT won't optimize it away.

There might be some place for another optimizations. If you use 64-bit CPU, then you may want use 64-bit CAS in order to set both `array[i][j]` and `array[i][j + 1]`, as those elements are placed within same 64-bit word.

Here is on of the possible implementations for java 9. If you use java 8 or lower, you can use `AtomicIntegerArray`.

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Container {

    private static final int LOCK_GRANULARITY = 128;

    private static final VarHandle AA = MethodHandles.arrayElementVarHandle(int[].class);

    private final int[][] array;
    private Lock[] locks = new Lock[LOCK_GRANULARITY];

    public Container(int xs, int ys){
        array = new int[ys][];
        for (int i = 0; i < ys; i++){
            array[i] = new int[xs];
        }

        locks = new Lock[LOCK_GRANULARITY];
        for(int i = 0; i < locks.length; i++) {
            locks[i] = new ReentrantLock(false);
        }
    }

    public void set2Int(int a, int b){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            int[] iArray = array[i];
            int[] iNextArray = array[i + 1];

            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length - 1; j++){
                if((int)AA.getOpaque(iArray, j) == 0 && (int)AA.getOpaque(iArray, j + 1) == 0){
                    if(update(i, j, a, i, j + 1, b)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if((int)AA.getOpaque(iArray, j) == 0 && (int)AA.getOpaque(iNextArray, j) == 0){
                    if(update(i, j, a, i, j + 1, b)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean update(int i1, int j1, int v1, int i2, int j2, int v2) {
        lock(i1, j1);
        lock(i2, j2);
        try {
            if(array[i1][j1] == 0 && array[i2][j2] == 0) {
                array[i1][j1] = v1;
                array[i2][j2] = v2;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            unlock(i2, j2);
            unlock(i1, j1);
        }
    }

    private void lock(int i, int j) {
        locks[Math.abs(hash(i, j) % locks.length)].lock();
    }

    private void unlock(int i, int j) {
        locks[Math.abs(hash(i, j) % locks.length)].unlock();
    }

    private int hash(int i, int j) {
        //TODO: choose good hash!
        return 31 * (i + 31 * j);
    }

    public int[][] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

> Would synchronize(array[i][j]){ synchronize(array[i][j+1]){
>   synchronize(array[i+1][j]}} be an thread-safe solution (inserted
>   before the first if)?
>   That will be thread-safe, I believe. However, locking for reading of every element might be slow.

Beside that, java uses the same `java.lang.Integer` objects for some int values. This means that if you have an array and every element is set to, let's say, 1, then every element will be the same object! And the synchronization will be slow, as you synchronize on the same object.

This code prints the same value, because every object is the same. Anyway, you might want to test both implementations and see what's faster.

```
    Integer[] array = new Integer[128];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = 5;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(array[i]));
    }
```

Comment: I am reading the documentation of `getOpaque` and fail to understand why it has to "read values from memory" (whatever that means); instead it says _Returns the value of a variable, accessed in program order_ which to me means that two reads of some variables using `getOpaque` will not be re-ordered. care to explain what you actually mean?